# Postgresql duplicate primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am woking on PG `9.2.14` on our production server I am facing some random issue.

Let's say its a table named `users` and `id` is the primary key in it.

When I am trying to reindex the table it give me following error:-

```
ERROR:  could not create unique index "users_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(339) is duplicated.
```

When I am trying to fetch user with the `339` id, there is no record. I am not sure if its PG's bug or I am doing something wrong.

Any one have faced such kind of problem?

Comment: I wonder if an existing index might be in use for building this new index, and the existing one is corrupt.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Any idea how can it be fixed?

Comment: Are you sure that you connect to the same database in psql console and application?

Comment: @peeyushsingla drop and recreate any indexes that might be causing this

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov Yeah I am 100 % sure its the same db.

Comment: @DavidAldridge ok, but as its Primary Key constraint it production server where this table is accessible will crash I think.

Comment: You don't have a primary key on there at the moment anyway, though, do you?

Comment: Another guess is mistype in table name when building index (the `on` clause).

Comment: Yeah id is Primary key and PG automatically add unique index constraint when you mark any column as primary key, same is the case over here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact problem was there were duplicate rows with same `id`.

I am not sure how it entered the db as there was primary key concern since the table was created.

The solution was I had to drop the primary key constraint

```
alter table users drop constraint users_pkey;
```

Then pulled the duplicate record with that id using.

```
Select * from users where id = 339;
```

Now it showed me around 4-5 rows with same id, deleted those rows and it worked.

I am not sure if there is `primary key constraint` on the column why PG don't show duplicate records, if its bug in `PG` or feature.

Answer (score 3):

Check the database. There is already a duplicate value in the table you want to add an index. Check for null value in the table. Seems like there are multiple rows taking null value in user_id.

Remove duplicates and you will be able to add the index. Happy Coding :)

Comment: To check that tried this `select id, count(*) from users group by id having count(*)>1;` but 0 records.

Comment: Which in rails is something like
`User.select(:id, 'count(*)').group(:id).having('count(*)>1')`